# Thread update SurfaceView

Tags: java, android, multithreading, runnable

I have a Class "Renderer" which takes a canvas of a surfaceHolder from a SurfaceView. I give those Renderer instance to my own Thread Class "MyThread" which takes the holder and the canvas and the renderer, in the run method of the MyThread-Class i have this:

```
    @Override
public void run(){
    super.run();
    while(true){
        renderer.RenderOneStep();
        this.holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(renderer.DisplayResult());
    }
}
```

renderer.RenderOneStep() computes the image. Renderer.DisplayResult() gives back a canvas.

My MainActivity extends Runnable so the MainActivity run()-Methods looks like this:

```
    @Override
public void run(){
    while(locker){
        if(!this.holder.getSurface().isValid()){
            continue;
        }
        Canvas canvas = this.holder.lockCanvas();
        Renderer renderer = new Renderer(new Scene(), canvas, new Vector3D(0f, 0f, 10.0f), 2,2);
        MyThread myThread = new MyThread(this.holder, canvas, renderer);
        myThread.run();
    }
}
```

In my onCreate-Method in my MainActivity i get myself the SurfaceView (e.g DrawingView) and the surface holder:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    DrawingView view = (DrawingView)findViewById(R.id.surface);
    this.holder = view.getHolder();

    this.thread = new Thread(this);
    thread.start();
}
```

So if i start my app i get this after a few seconds:

> 12-15 15:20:34.944  21082-21096/com.example.standardbenutzer.adelpath A/libc﹕ Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 21096 (Thread-633)
>   12-15 15:20:34.944  21082-21096/com.example.standardbenutzer.adelpath A/libc﹕ Send stop signal to pid:21082 in void debuggerd_signal_handler(int, siginfo_t*, void*)

How can i refresh my SurfaceView continuously?